# How to create SSRS report for Dynamics 365 online in VS2017?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I need to create SSRS report (.rdl) for Dynamics 365 online in Visual Studio 2017.

As I found on web I need  "Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension" and "SQL Server Data Tools" installed in visual studio.

There is a lot of guidelines how to achieve this goal on web. But all instructions are for VS2010, 2012 or 2015 but non for VS2017.

I have VS2017 only and I found no way how to create SSRS reports for Dyn 365 in VS2017. Instructions for earlier VS are not working.

Is there some way? Some hack how to do it?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Not working means errors?

Comment: Report Authoring Extensions don't work with VS2017, you need max VS2015. I believe seeing some random webpage explaining how to "patch" the setup to make it work on 2017 but didn't try

Comment: "Not working" means unable to install mentioned software for vs2017.